# Dynamic variable in $in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have following variables. (I am using this query in mongoose, node )

```
var splitDates=currentDate.split('-');//2019-12-09
currentDate=splitDates[0]+splitDates[1]+splitDates[2] //returns 20191209
previousDate= splitDates[0]+splitDates[1]+splitDates[2]-1;
```

I want it in the mongoDB query:

```
{ batchRef: { $in: [/20191209/, /20191210/] } }, // this is static values and works.
{ batchRef: { $in: ['/'+previousDate+'/','/'+currentDate+'/'] } }, // this doesnt work!
```

am I missing something? 
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a javascript date transformation question.

You can use the following code to get a string array for a given  date and previous date to be used in $in query.

```
const inputDateString = "2019-12-09";

const currentDate = new Date(inputDateString);
const previousDate = new Date(inputDateString);
previousDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);

let inArray = [];

inArray.push(inputDateString.split("-").join(""));
inArray.push(
  previousDate
    .toISOString()
    .slice(0, 10)
    .split("-")
    .join("")
);

console.log(inArray);
```

inArray will have these 2 items:

```
[ '20191209', '20191208' ]
```

Now we can use this in the query like this:

```
  { batchRef: { $in: inArray } }
```

Please not that I assumed that inputDateString is always in this format with 10 characters, like `2019-01-31`  or `2019-01-01`